# How to distinct the record when using Group By?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Hallo,
I am having the table (look below), which having 4 records. Notice that ColumnA and ColumnB are having the same value, and ColumnC and columnD will have different value.

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
------- ------- ------- -------
xx      yy      AAA     333
xx      yy      BBB     555
xx      yy      AAA     333
xx      yy      BBB     555
```

I was trying to select the whole record using Group By query like this:

```
SELECT ColumnC from TableA GROUP BY ColumnC;
```

This query only shows me ColumnC but my expectation is to select the whole record not only ColumnC.

UPDATE: My expected output is:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
------- ------- ------- -------
xx      yy      AAA     333
xx      yy      BBB     555
```

May I know how can I do this?

THanks @!

Comment: If you want to group only by ColumnC, and want "the whole record", then what are the values that you want for the rest of the columns?

Comment: For what database?  Because the behavior is different between ANSI spec and vendor implementation - see my comment on Egor4eg's answer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The answer might help refine the answers.

Comment: @Lamak: I have added my expected output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columnC ORDER BY columnA) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        )
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Change the `ORDER BY` clause to control which of the records holding the duplicate will be returned (now that with the least value of `columnA` is).

Comment: According to your query, I must order by columnD so that I can only get my expected output. If I order by other column, the rn value will be different like 3,7,8,9. May I know why this happen? BTW, "partition by" is a new term to me.

Comment: @huahsin68: my query does not even mention `columnD`.

Answer (score 4):

You could put all of the columns in your SELECT and GROUP BY clauses:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD 
FROM 
    TableA 
GROUP BY
    ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD
```

This would basically be equivalent to

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    TableA
```

but is more explicit. As has been pointed out by OMG Ponies, the syntax can vary between DBMSs. In some you may be able to simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA GROUP BY ColumnC
```

Comment: I was doing it in Oracle, and I did try out that before, but the output is exactly the same as the original table. I did try SELECT distinct(columnC), distinct(columnD) from tableA; but it is not working as well. This query will give me an error: ORA-00936: missing expression.

Comment: @huahsin68: [`DISTINCT`](http://psoug.org/definition/DISTINCT.htm) applies to a *row*, not to a column. You can't force some columns to be distinct and some not by simply putting DISTINCT where you want. Here's how you go: `SELECT DISTINCT columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD FROM tableA`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS SQL the following will get you what you need:    `SELECT ColumnC,* from TableA GROUP BY ColumnC;`

in Oracle, I believe that `select ColumnC, TableA.* from TableA GROUP BY COLUMNC;` will get you there.

Comment: I'm doing it in Oracle, and this doesn't work. It give me an error ORA-00936: missing expression.

Comment: I retagged the question to include oracle. My answer will work for MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from TableA GROUP BY ColumnC;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't include columns in a SELECT without them being in an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Cory Larson: Actually, that is what the ANSI (92?) SQL spec specifies - but few databases implemented it.  MySQL and SQLite are the only ones I know of that support optional `GROUP BY` columns.

Comment: @CoryLarson: It (sadly) works by default in MySQL, where it chooses the value from an arbitrary row; you can turn it off with the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) sql_mode. Also, the latest SQL standard apparently makes it much more complicated, if the DB knows that a column is "functionally dependent" on the group-by columns it doesn't itself need to be in the group by or aggregated.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I stand corrected... this usually* doesn't work.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm doing it in Oracle, this query give me an error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 0):

You would want to select all of the columns and you then need to group by with Column C being first:
SELECT * FROM TableA GROUP BY ColumnC, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnD